# Parsing Map Response Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting an object which contain the map data type

e.g:

```
{
    'key1': value1,
    'key2' : value2,
    'key3' : value3
}
```

`Map<String, boolean>` now i want to parse this in the angular and store the value in map format.

```
this.commonService.getData(queryParam).subscribe(data => {
     // Data which is map and i want to pare this here
}
```

Can anyone please help me how we can do ?

Comment: In your example, you have an object with string values, but in `Map<string, boolean>`, the value is of type boolean. It also doesn't make sense to say that your object contains the "map data type", An object doesn't contain a type, it has the form of a certain type. It's also confusing how you use the term "parse", which usually refers to creating an object/value from a string, but in your case it seems like you already have an object.

Comment: that said, you should be able to use `new Map(Object.entries(obj))`

Comment: @ShamPooSham as i told that my key are in string and value are in boolean , i have corrected the quotes from the value. also, i have check and from backend we are returning Map<string,boolean>

Comment: Ok, so what the backend returns is not necessarily what you'll get. If you use nodejs express, it will probably serialize it to json. Angular's http service then parses the json into a js object. Do you have to convert it to a Map? You can do the same things with regular js objects, the difference lies in performance of different operations. Also, did you try `new Map(Object.entries(data))`?

Comment: The thing is that the body of a http request is encoded as a string, which isn't good for representing all kinds of data structures. Most systems use json to transfer data between backend and frontend, which has a very strict set of possible values; objects, arrays, strings, booleans, numbers and null are the accepted types. Having this minimalistic approach means that the api backends can be written in whatever language they want without needing to implement complex data types such as javascript's `Map` or `Set`. It's then up to the frontend to use the data as they see fit.